# Autocovariance function depends on lag only - intuitive meaning

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity, lags

On an intuitive level, what does it mean for a weekly stationary time series the autocovariance *depends on lag only*, that is why dependence on *lag* is a "nice" property?

Comment: You have focused on the wrong half of the statement: the point is that the autocovariance does *not* depend on both times, but only on their difference, which is a *huge* simplification.

Comment: Right, but I actually want to figure out what I've asked: the intuitive meaning of "depending on the difference", as to how can I explain in layman's terms what "dependence on the difference of time points" means

Comment: You appear to be asking what "weakly stationary" means, then.

Comment: Not really, I'm asking about the intuitive meaning of "autocovariance function depending on the lag only". But I think I got it: the dependence on the lag means that no matter where I take let's say 3 months period, I'll have the same autocovariance function value.

Comment: What I'm trying to explain is that "covariance depending on lag only" is the main part of what "weakly second order stationary" means.  (The other two parts are that the mean is invariant and the variance is finite.)

Comment: Well I know it's a part of a wider definition of a weak-stationarity, my question was precisely about the intuitive meaning of this exact statement and only this statement "covariance depending on lag only". But as I wrote above, I think I got it.